# native crashes for android 8.0 devices tgkill

Tags: android, crash, native

I am getting native crashes for android 8.0 devices.The crashes only 
    occur on Devices running Android 8+.
    I found a lot native crash in "Android Vitals - ANRs & crashes".
    I can not reproduce these issue.
    Devices (all with Android 8.0):
            Galaxy S7 edge (hero2lte)
            Galaxy S7 (herolte) 
            Galaxy S8 (dreamlte)
            Galaxy A5(2017) (a5y17lte)
            Galaxy Note8 (greatlte)

```
### Crash log  ###
#00  pc 000000000004b3ac  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
#01  pc 000000000001a473  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+54)
#02  pc 000000000033a8bb  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEPKc+370)
#03  pc 000000000033aeb3  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art7Runtime7AborterEPKc+10)
#04  pc 00000000003f3419  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN7android4base10LogMessageD1Ev+456)
#05  pc 0000000000171b07  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying17PushOntoMarkStackEPNS_
6mirror6ObjectE+574)
#06  pc 00000000001762a5  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art2gc9collector17ConcurrentCopying4CopyEPNS_
6mirror6ObjectES5_NS_12MemberOffsetE+2524)
#07  pc 00000000000a9ea3  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3art11ReadBarrier4MarkEPNS_6mirror6ObjectE+610)
#08  pc 00000000002dbfc7  /system/lib/libart.so 
(_ZN3artL9Field_getEP7_JNIEnvP8_jobjectS3_+694)
#09  pc 0000000000250fa5  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat 
(java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructorInternal [DEDUPED]+92)
#10  pc 000000000000297b  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
```

Comment: We see a similar issue. Seems to be a bug in android 8.0.0 with garbage collection. We haven't found a solution yet.  Actually, we only see the crash on android 8.0.0. Not in 8.1.0, as there was a fix provided by Google team. 

References:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65268761

Fix:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/art/+/430379/

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `minifyEnabled` to `false` in `android/app/build.gradle` fixed it for me.

It only crashes when the app is downloaded from Google Play while in Debug mode works fine.